# C# How can i show Notification Popup Form to all user?

Tags: c#, notifications, popup, devexpress, windows-forms-designer

I create a notification popup form on Visual Studio with c# windows form.

The code is like that:

```
  PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
                    popup.Image = Properties.Resources.information;
                    popup.TitleText = "Notification!";
                    popup.ContentText = txt_message.Text;
                    popup.Popup();
```

When i call the function it is working but just for me. I want to show the message for all users same time. Can i do that ?

Comment: Please, define "all users". All users of current OS, all users of the same service, database? Which one?

Comment: Are you taking about users on other machines / in other processes?

Comment: What I mean by all users is:
Too many users are using the software at the same time. There are different staff members and they all log into the software with their own usernames and passwords. I want to convey this message to all users who are online in the software.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the codes below, but it just works for me. When i click the button it is working but some other user couldn't see that.

`PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
 popup.Image = Properties.Resources.information;
 popup.TitleText = "Notification!";
 popup.ContentText = txt_message.Text;
 popup.Popup(); `